# Buying a 6 month round-trip international ticket but also flying domestic with same airline during the 6mo. void. Is OK?

Tags: air-travel

I want to buy a 6 month round-trip international ticket from the US. After using the first leg, I plan to continue travelling on other airlines and return to the US about a month later.

I then plan to do some domestic and possibly international travel during that time on the carrier I bought the round-trip ticket from. I will return to the original round-trip location to take the return flight home. Will this cause a problem?

Answer (score 4):

That should not be an issue. You can book other flights *between* the legs of a ticket, with the same and other airlines, as much as you want (and can fit in).

You can even book other round-trips that *overlap* the started one.
Example: ticket A out on 1., back on 20. Buy another ticket B out on 15, back on 30. Buy a reverse ticket C, ‘back’ on 7., ‘out’ on 25. Then fly the six legs *on their proper days*, but in a wild sequence: A out, C back; B out, A back; C out, B back.
For people that fly every week, this is a common way to save money, as tickets spread over more than a week are typically cheaper.

The only thing you can’t do is *skip* any leg on a multi-leg or round-trip ticket - you typically *void* = *lose* all following legs of that ticket.